# SP2010 autologin with FireFox

Tags: 2010, login, single-sign-on, firefox, workgroup

I need to use auto log on for a bunch of computers that run FireFox as default browser. The **BIG PROBLEM** is that all of these computers aren't part of the domain, but they all exist in a workgroup. (don't ask me why...) So is there anyone who knows how to set single sign-on up in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to your Firefox address bar and type `about:config`.  This will bring up the internal config editor, which allows you to set all kinds of properties that influence Firefoxs behavior.  Look for the key called "`network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`".  Set that keys value to a comma separated list of servers you want NTLM auth for.  So if your internal SharePoint sites are on servers called Larry and Mo, use larry,mo.  You can also add the same value to the key "`network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris`".  Its unclear to me if that second one is required, but I set it, and everything works.  Now SharePoint works like a champ, and authenticates automatically.

Comment: Negotiate auth is probably for if Kerberos has been configured, and Firefox will presumably just pass your ticket through when accessing the server.

Answer (score 0):

This might not fix it. An additional setting should be changed as well.

network.auth.force-generic-ntlm should be set to true.

network.auth.force-generic-ntlm | user set | boolean | true